# Populate Lightning-DataTable With Case Data

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lightning-data-service

I am trying to populate a Lightning Web Component that I put together with particular Case fields.  No matter what I try, I can't get any data into my Lightning-DataTable.  Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you add relevant code snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Not possible.

Lightning data service is meant to work on single record and you need `List` of records in data-table. Although we get the property `records` (which is single record) in data-service, there is nothing in roadmap as of now which shows data-service will be made to get list of records.

As of today, you should get the list of records from Apex only.

Comment: This could be possibly true if the OP is trying to fetch records using LDS. With the current state of the post except for the tag, it doesn't suggest that how OP is trying to retrieve the records, I think we need to see a bit of code here.

Comment: I ended up writing custom Apex using a Model to capture the fields the way I wanted to display them in the grid.